# Interrupt forEach_root in RenderScript from Java-Side?

Tags: android, renderscript

I am writing an android application and I use renderscript for some complex calculation (I am simulating a magnetic pendulum) that is performed on each pixel of a bitmap (using script.forEach_root(...)). This calculation might last from tenth of a second to up to about 10 seconds or even more, depending on the input parameters.

I want to keep the application responsive and allow users to change parameters without waiting. Therefore I would like to interrupt a running calculation based on user input on the Java-Side of the program. Hence, can I interrupt a forEach_root-call?

I already tried some solutions but they either do not work or do not fully satisfy me:

- Add a variable containing a cancel-Flag to RenderScript and check its status in root: Does not work because I cannot change variables using set while forEach_root is running (they are synchronized - I guess for good reasons).
- Split the image up into multiple tiles: This is a possible solution and currently the one I favor the most, yet it is only a work around because calculating a single tile might also take several seconds.

Since I am new to renderscript I am wondering whether there are some other solutions which I was not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to cancel a running kernel for RenderScript. I think that your tiling approach is probably the best solution today, which you should be able to implement using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Script.LaunchOptions.html when you begin kernel execution.